# How to use nested class eachother with hive?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

Hello I have three nested classes, I want it to store them in box which provided by hive package, I inserted some codes but I dont know is this the true way, How can I store them, can someone help me ?

```
@HiveType(typeId : 1)
class CategoryModel extends HiveObject{
  CategoryModel(
      { this.categoryId,
        this.categoryImagePath,
        this.categoryName,
        this.categoryColor,
        this.subCategoryModels});

  @HiveField(0)
  final int categoryColor;

  @HiveField(1)
  HiveList <SubCategoryModel> subCategoryModels;

  @HiveField(2)
  int categoryId;

  @HiveField(3)
  String categoryImagePath;

  @HiveField(4)
  String categoryName;


}
```

```
@HiveType(typeId : 2)
class SubCategoryModel extends HiveObject{
  SubCategoryModel({
    this.subCategoryId,
    this.subCategoryImagePath,
    this.subCategoryName,
    this.categoryColor,
    this.recipeId,
    HiveList<Ingredient>ingredients,
    this.recipePhotoDir,
    this.recordedVoiceDir,
    bool isCompeted});

  @HiveField(0)
  final Color categoryColor;

  @HiveField(1)
  final double recipeId;

  @HiveField(2)
  bool isCompleted;

  @HiveField(3)
  int subCategoryId;

  @HiveField(4)
  String subCategoryImagePath;

  @HiveField(5)
  String subCategoryName;

  @HiveField(6)
  HiveList <Ingredient> ingredients ;

  @HiveField(7)
  String recipePhotoDir;

  @HiveField(8)
  String recordedVoiceDir;

}
```

```
@HiveType(typeId: 3)
class Ingredient extends HiveObject{
  Ingredient({this.ingredientName,
              this.dropDownValue,
              this.ingredientAmount});

  @HiveField(0)
  final ingredientName;

  @HiveField(1)
  String dropDownValue;

  @HiveField(2)
  String ingredientAmount;
}
```

```
class HiveHelper{
  Box <CategoryModel>categoryModels;
  CategoryModel categoryModel;

  void initState() async {
    if(categoryModels==null){
      var _directory =await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      Hive
        ..init(_directory.path)
        ..registerAdapter(CategoryModelAdapter())
        ..registerAdapter(SubCategoryModelAdapter())
        ..registerAdapter(IngredientAdapter());

      categoryModels = await Hive.openBox<CategoryModel>('categoryModels');

    }
  }
  void addCategoryModel(CategoryModel categoryModel)async{
    await categoryModels.add(categoryModel);
  }
  Future <Box> getCategoryModels()async{
    return categoryModels;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to cut down your code to just the part that has the error? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @ygzkrmtc have you found the right way of doing that? I am facing the same scenario!